# Difference between suspend and sleep in Thread in c#

Tags: c#

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Thread.suspend(5000);
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: The difference is that you should use neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep means thread sleep in 5000 (msec).
suspend means thread stop when you resume the thread start.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 7):

[Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep(v=vs.110).aspx) is used on a single thread and it suspends a thread for a period of time. [Whereas suspend is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also check the Remarks from MSDN about Suspend:

> Do not use the Suspend and Resume methods to synchronize the
>   activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread
>   is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it
>   holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in
>   the AppDomain might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is
>   executing a class constructor, other threads in the AppDomain that
>   attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very
>   easily.

Comment: Any chance it is about Java? The question is about .NET (C#)

Comment: Thanks for your reply